# Removing a specific Field in a map of a state always remove the last element of it

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have in my functionnal component define a state with useState like that :

```
 const [appointmentList, setAppointmentList] = useState([]);
```

This state reprensent a list of form, i can add as many as i want like this :

```
const addAppointment = useCallback(() => {
  setAppointmentList([...appointmentList, {id: uuid()}]);
}, [appointmentList]);
```

But i got a probleme when it's come to delete the appointments. To do it, i use this useCallback :

```
const removeAppointment = useCallback((i) => {
  let newAppointmentList = [...appointmentList];
  newAppointmentList.splice(i, 1);
  setAppointmentList(newAppointmentList)
}, [appointmentList]);
```

It's work well to delete the correct appointment in the state but it's always delete the last appointment in the view of my application.

For exemple, i have 2 form filled with values. I click to delete the first form, in my state i now only got the values of the second form in the appointmentList state, but in my view, the last form as been deleted so i still got the first form with his values...

I think the probleme might come from the fact that my function only erase the correct appointment in the state, then the map realise that the appointmentList as reduce and then the map render the most recent appointment not the on selected to be deleted.

My Form look like this :

```
return(
  <div>
    {appointmentList.map((appointment, index) => (
      <Row key={`${index}`} id={index}>
            <Col>
              <Field
                name={`appointments[${index}].title`}
                id="title"
                component={InputTextField}
                value={appointment.title || ""}
                onChange={e => handleChange(index, e)}
              />
              <Field
                manyOther field
              />
             <Button
                 theme={BUTTON_THEMES.SECONDARY}
                 size={BUTTON_SIZES.SMALL}
                 onClick={() => removeAppointment(index)}
                >
           </Col>
       </Row>
    ))}
    <div>
      <Button
         theme={BUTTON_THEMES.SECONDARY}
         size={BUTTON_SIZES.SMALL}
         onClick={addAppointment}
       >
    </div>
 </div>
```

So how can i delete the correct form ?

Thank you for your help = )

Comment: you don't need to useCallback here. Remove useCallback and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, it's not working

Comment: did u `console.log` after `newAppointmentList.splice(i, 1);` to see if you deleted correct values?

Comment: Yes, i have check my console, it's delete the correct values in the State

Answer (score 0):

This is a working demo. Are your codes similar? Because mine are working.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-hooks-tv38kk?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [appointmentList, setAppointmentList] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

  const addAppointment = () => {
    setAppointmentList([...appointmentList, { id: uuid() }]);
  };

  const removeAppointment = (i) => {
    let newAppointmentList = [...appointmentList];
    newAppointmentList.splice(i, 1);
    setAppointmentList(newAppointmentList);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        {appointmentList.map((item, index) => {
          return <div key={item.id}> {item.id} <button onClick={() => removeAppointment(index)}>delete</button></div>;
        })}
      </div>
      <button onClick={addAppointment} >Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: My code is similar but i use Fields from redux-form instead of normal input

Comment: well, as you see, since the state setting and state is retrieval are correct, then the problem doesn't line in these codes. Which means your rendering problem probably lies with other codes.

Comment: Do you think in can delete directly the fields, then set the state ?

Comment: I thnk you can edit my codesandbox, and reproduce your error. Then I can see bug you are seeing

Comment: Another possible cause of bug is because you are using `key={index}` in `Row`, which is unstable. You can try using `key={item.id}` to see if it improves the situation.

Comment: I just tried to change of key, and it's didn't work, Here as you ask an example with a sandbox   [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-brook-o5wpjh?file=/src/App.js) but i can't add a appointment it's weird it's should work

Comment: You cannot add appointment because in your code, you used `<button onClick={removeAppointment(index)}>` This caused `removeAppointment(index)` to be called on **every render**. The correct code should be `<button onClick={() => removeAppointment(index)}>`

Comment: You are using redux form so you need to create the form context etc, which I hope you can read up more at https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/gettingstarted.md/. To me, unless redux is really needed, I won't choose to use redux form, and simply create my own form components.